# Value of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

Got stuck at this error:

> 3169-3190/com.meisolsson.app E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value [{"type":0,"can_see_custom_stories":true,"display":"","name":"jenniaim"},{"type":0,"can_see_custom_stories":true,"display":"","name":"lucasgardebrand"},{"type":0,"can_see_custom_stories":true,"display":"","name":"herr_anderzzon"},{"type":0,"can_see_custom_stories":true,"display":"","name":"chrillebile"},{"type":0,"can_see_custom_stories":true,"display":"","name":"meisolsson"},{"type":0,"can_see_custom_stories":true,"display":"","name":"sakanapanda"},{"type":0,"can_see_custom_stories":true,"display":"Team Snapchat","name":"teamsnapchat"},{"type":0,"can_see_custom_stories":true,"display":"","name":"fabianlindfors"},{"type":0,"can_see_custom_stories":true,"display":"Katja","name":"katjaawesome"},{"type":0,"can_see_custom_stories":true,"display":"","name":"swimkey"},{"type":1,"can_see_custom_stories":true,"display":"","name":"agnesholmberg"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

So here is the code:

```
public class JSONParser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", LoginActivity.Suser));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", LoginActivity.Spass));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return  jObj;

}
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    getJSONFromUrl("http://flapplabs.se/development/snapchat/friends.php");
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: What don't you understand about the exception?

Comment: It is a json array, there is no object in it that is why you cannot convert it

Comment: I'm very bad at the JSON thing, thanks for the help

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`[..]` means it should be an `JSONArray` and `{..}` means it should be a `JSONObject`.

Therefore:

```
try {
        JSONArray jObj = new JSONArray(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Even though I had a single JSON object it was stored in an array as 
 Hariharan has pointed out with the square brackets [ { items:items, ... } ]

My solution was simply to parse out the only object, located in array position [0] like this

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(stringIn);

JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
```