# org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject in Android

Tags: php, android, json, object

I got this error :

> org.json.JSONException: Value [] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

I am trying to show some records from database inside android app according to filter. Postman shows me correct results shows error. I use basicallly same methods in second app and it works.

PHP script :

```
function findUsers($odkial, $co){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT Meno, RodneCislo, PIK FROM zamestnanci WHERE $odkial LIKE ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $co);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($Meno, $RC, $PIK);

        $foundUsers = array(); 

        while($stmt->fetch()){
        $user  = array();
        $user['meno'] = $Meno;
        $user['rodnecislo'] = $RC; 
        $user['pik'] = $PIK; 

        array_push($foundUsers, $user); 
        }

        return $foundUsers; 
        }
```

Android code method for getting some parameters from edit text and spinner:

```
public void hladajZaznamy(){
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    String pod = podla.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String co = "%"+podlac.getText().toString()+"%";
    params.put("PodlaCoho", pod);
    params.put("Co", co);

    PerformNetworkRequest request = new PerformNetworkRequest(Api.HLADAJ_ZAMESTNANCA, params, CODE_POST_REQUEST);
    request.execute();

}
```

Android code networkrequest :

```
 private class PerformNetworkRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    String url;

    HashMap<String, String> params;

    int requestCode;

    PerformNetworkRequest(String url, HashMap<String, String> params, int requestCode) {
        this.url = url;
        this.params = params;
        this.requestCode = requestCode;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(s); // HERE IS THE ERROR
            if (!object.getBoolean("error")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), object.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                saveRecords(object.getJSONArray("foundUsers"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //the network operation will be performed in background
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();

        if (requestCode == CODE_POST_REQUEST)
            return requestHandler.sendPostRequest(url, params);


        if (requestCode == CODE_GET_REQUEST)
            return requestHandler.sendGetRequest(url);

        return null;
    }
}
```

And some postman results for example when `PodlaCoho = Meno` and `Co = %TESTTEST%` :

```
{"error":false,"message":"Zamestnanci uspesne vyhladani","foundUsers":[{"meno":"TESTTEST","rodnecislo":"1111225555","pik":"111111"}]}
```

Thanks for any advice :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Value of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245957/value-of-type-org-json-jsonarray-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonobject)

Comment: private void saveRecords(JSONArray foundUsers) throws JSONException {
        userList.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < foundUsers.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = foundUsers.getJSONObject(i);

            userList.add(new User(
                    obj.getString("meno"),
                    obj.getString("rodnecislo"),
                    obj.getString("pik")
            ));
        }
        UserAdapter adapter = new UserAdapter(userList);
        zoznam.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the response String you are converting into `JSONObject` should be in form of`JSONArray` so change the errored line to this.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    JSONArray objectArray = new JSONArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < objectArray.length(); i++) {
        //here you can iterate through the array elements and find respective JSONObject and/or other values.
    }
}
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: looks good but what can i use as argument into saveRecords ? method saveRecords added into question

Comment: I see the calls to saveRecord method but what this method does, and also I see this method below the part where you get error.. so How this method gets executed if you have error above this code..